# Why does Android keep DX when it was replaced by D8?

Tags: android, dx, android-d8

Why does Android still keep DX along its newer replacement D8?

```
cd cmdline-tools/build-tools/30.0.3 && ls d*
```

Result:

```
d8  dexdump  dx
```

Here is the program I used (file *Primes.java*):

```java
class Primes {

    private static boolean isPrime(int p)
    {
        for (int i=2; i<p; i++) {
            for (int j=2; j<p; j++) {
                if (i*j == p) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=2; i<100; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                System.out.format("%d ", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I compile it to *.dex* files:

```
javac Primes.java
```

Result:

```
cmdline-tools/build-tools/30.0.3/dx --dex --output dx/classes.dex Primes.class
cmdline-tools/build-tools/30.0.3/d8       --output d8             Primes.class
cmdline-tools/build-tools/30.0.3/dexdump -d dx/classes.dex > dx.human
cmdline-tools/build-tools/30.0.3/dexdump -d d8/classes.dex > d8.human
```

Then I clean up addresses, register names and comments to be able to compare:

```
cat dx.human | awk "/\'main\'/,/catches/" | sed "s/.*|[0-9a-f]*: //g" | sed "s/\/\/.*//g" | sed "s/Ljava.*//g" | sed "s/v[0-9]/v/g" | sed "s/v[0-9]/v/g" > dx.main.human
cat d8.human | awk "/\'main\'/,/catches/" | sed "s/.*|[0-9a-f]*: //g" | sed "s/\/\/.*//g" | sed "s/Ljava.*//g" | sed "s/v[0-9]/v/g" | sed "s/v[0-9]/v/g" > d8.main.human
```

They are **almost** identical then, but not entirely:

```
$ diff -u dx.main.human d8.main.human
--- dx.main.human    2021-04-12 19:49:37.110476376 +0300
+++ d8.main.human    2021-04-12 19:49:44.650101698 +0300
@@ -2,11 +2,11 @@
...
-      registers     : 7
+      registers     : 5
...
 const/4 v, #int 2
 const/16 v, #int 100
 if-ge v, v, 001f
@@ -14,13 +14,13 @@
 move-result v
 if-eqz v, 001c
 sget-object v,
-const-string v, "%d "  <----------------+
 const/4 v, #int 1                       |
 new-array v, v, [                       |
 const/4 v, #int 0                       |
 invoke-static {v},                      |
 move-result-object v                    |
 aput-object v, v, v                     |
+const-string v, "%d "  <----------------+
 invoke-virtual {v, v, v},
 add-int/lit8 v, v, #int 1
 goto 0001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[The path to DX deprecation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/02/the-path-to-dx-deprecation.html)* lays out the deprecation plan.

Exactly what version of the command line tools this will go away in is still a little up in the air because of dependencies uncovered during the last year.